# Хранение картинок на сервере

Tags: php, изображения

На одном сайте php, получилось много картинок из-за типа сайта.
Сейчас уже более 20к и думаю будет больше.
Возник вопрос как их хранить на сервере? Сейчас они лежат в одной папке img.
В базе хранится только имя файла.
У меня появилась мысль что можно раскидывать по папкам уже на данном этапе и в базу записывать путь.
Полагаю это лишняя нагрузка когда в одной папке слишком много файлов. Или в этом нет смысла?
т.к. файл запрашивается по пути site/img/namefile.jpg
и кол-во файлов в папке не имеет значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно взять md5-hex от содержимого файла и отделить два уровня директорий:
`img/hashed/3A/EA/B567...789.jpg`

Заодно дедупликация одинаковых файлов и плюс к безопасности.