# Flask как правильно сохранить файл\имя файла?

Tags: python, django, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Как правильно сохранить имя файла в базу?
Я из формы получаю имя файла "image.jpg"(и сам файл) в бд сохраняется так же "image.jpg",если попадается ещё раз файл с таким же именем "image.jpg" в бд сохраняется так же "image.jpg",а у меня в папку естественно уже как "image_1.jpg".
Подскажите как правильно сохранять имя файла чтобы я его потом мог использовать?

blueprint.py

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from models import War
from .forms import WarForm
from app import db

war = Blueprint('war', __name__, template_folder="templates")
from flask_uploads import configure_uploads, IMAGES, UploadSet

from app import app

images = UploadSet('war',IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, images)

@war.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_news():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        file = request.files['image']
        if file.filename != '':
            images.save(file)
            print(file.filename)

        try:
            news = War(title=title,body=body,image=file.filename)
            db.session.add(news)
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print("Some error")

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    form = WarForm()
    return render_template('war/index.html',form=form)
```

config.py

```
class Configuration(object):
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:1@localhost/server'
    SECRET_KEY = "PASSWORD"

    SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = 'salt'
    SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH = 'sha512_crypt'
    UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST = 'static/images'
```

Comment: почему нельзя сохранять и в БД и в папку под уникальными названиями? например `ДД-ММ-ГГ-ЧЧ-мм`?

Comment: Что значит «правильно»?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166360/395779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае коректнее хранить на файловой системе файл с уникальным именем, а в БД хранить пользовательское имя файла и уникальное имя файла, с которым файл записан на файловой системе. Уникальное имя можно получить воспользовавшись, например uuid1() https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html
Если принципиально необходимо хранить файл именно с исходным именем, то под каждый файл можно генерировать уникальную папку, либо разработать метод разрешения колизий имен.